# Two Way Binding C# . Textbox and object of self made class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

In the MSDN documents I found some articles, which say it wouldn't be any problem to bind two objects to each other. So I tried this with a WindowsForms application. The first object is a `TextBox`, the second object is an instance of the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public class XmlEmulator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string Captionfield;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged()
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(""));
    }

    public string Caption
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Captionfield;
        }
        set
        {
            this.Captionfield = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Binding the `TextBox` to the `XmlEmulator.Captionfield` works properly, but how can I bind the `Captionfield` oroperty to the `TextBox.text` property? Does the `XmlEmulator` class have to inherit from the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` to get the `Databindings` property? In this case I have run into trouble because I have already implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Make sure you are binding the Caption property rather than Captionfield as the Captionfield is private.

Answer (score 1):

> In the MSDN documents I found some articles, which say it wouldn't be any problem to bind two objects to each other.

That's not correct, the one one the objects must be a `Control`, while the other could be any object (including `Control`). When you bind to a control property, you can specify if the binding is "one way" or "two way", and when to update one or the other side via [Binding.DataSourceUpdateMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Binding.ControlUpdateMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.controlupdatemode(v=vs.110).aspx). I guess your binding is already "two way" if you have used a standard code like this

```
XmlEmulator emulator = ...;
TextBox textBox = ....;
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", emulator, "Caption");
```

and if you modify the text box, the emulator property will update. Just note that the default value for `DataSourceUpdateMode` property is `OnValidation`, so the emulator will be updated after you leave the text box. If you want it to happen immediately as you type, then you need set is to `OnPropertyChanged` by modifying the above code like this

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", emulator, "Caption", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

In fact the `Add` method returns a `Binding` object, so you can use something like this

```
var binding = textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", emulator, "Caption");
```

and explore/modify the binding properties.